# Dictionary Algorithm, Computing all Case options

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, brute-force

So I am building this algorithm as part of a larger project for a Network security class...

the jist of this part is that i have been given a dictionary, and I need to find every possible option for a word in both upper and lowercase..

example....

to
tO
To
TO

My first thought was this it looked alot like counting in binary, and thats what i have based this algorith off of...

only problem is.... its pretty freaking slow....

here is the code i have
public class Launch {

```
  Instructors hash code in integers  
    //106 | 31 | 65 | 19 | 230 | 164 | 247 | 192 | 75 | 119 | 40 | 12 | 5 |
    //402 | 78 | 87 | 193 | 75 | 125 | 234 | 113 | 109 | 181 | 229 | 216 | 
    //56 | 76 | 109 | 213 | 247 | 123 | 126
    char c1 = (char) 106;
    char c2 = (char) 31;
    char c3 = (char) 65;
    char c4 = (char) 19;
    char c5 = (char) 230;
    char c6 = (char) 164;
    char c7 = (char) 247;
    char c8 = (char) 192;
    char c9 = (char) 75;
    char c10 = (char) 119;
    char c11 = (char) 40;
    char c12 = (char) 12;
    char c13 = (char) 5;
    char c14 = (char) 402;
    char c15 = (char) 78;
    char c16 = (char) 87;
    char c17 = (char) 193;
    char c18 = (char) 75;
    char c19 = (char) 125;
    char c20 = (char) 234;
    char c21 = (char) 113;
    char c22 = (char) 109;
    char c23 = (char) 181;
    char c24 = (char) 229;
    char c25 = (char) 216;
    char c26 = (char) 56;
    char c27 = (char) 76;
    char c28 = (char) 109;
    char c29 = (char) 213;
    char c30 = (char) 247;
    char c31 = (char) 123;
    char c32 = (char) 126;

    String mystery = ("" + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 + c6 + c7 + c8 + c9 + c10 + c11
            + c12 + c13 + c14 + c15 + c16 + c17 + c18 + c19 + c20 + c21
            + c22 + c23 + c24 + c25 + c26 + c27 + c28 + c29 + c30 + c31 + c32);
    System.out.print(mystery);

    File dictionary = new File("Dictionary");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(dictionary);

    String _word;
    char[] word;
    int length;
    boolean[] binVal;
    int[] iteratorVal;
    int iterator;
    boolean flag = false;
    int counter = 0;

    while (in.hasNextLine() && !flag) {
        _word = in.nextLine();
        //counter++;
        //if (counter % 10 == 0) {
        //    System.out.println(_word);
       // }else if(counter > 1000){
        //    counter = 0;
        //}

        word = _word.toCharArray();

        length = (int) (Math.pow(2, word.length));

        binVal = new boolean[word.length];
        iteratorVal = new int[word.length];
        iterator = length;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            binVal[i] = true;
            iterator = iterator / 2;                
          //System.out.print(iterator + "||");
            iteratorVal[i] = iterator;
        }

        String permutation = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
            //System.out.println(permutation);
            permutation = "";

            for (int n = 0; n < word.length; n++) {

                if (binVal[n] == true) {
                    permutation = permutation + Character.toLowerCase(word[n]);
                    //make uppercase [n]
                } else {
                    permutation = permutation + Character.toUpperCase(word[n]);
                    //make lowercase [n]
                }
            }
            for (int n = 0; n < iteratorVal.length; n++) {
                if (i % iteratorVal[n] == 0) {
                    binVal[n] = !binVal[n];
                }
            }

            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            messageDigest.update(permutation.getBytes());
            String encryptedString = new String(messageDigest.digest());
            if (encryptedString.equals(mystery)) {
                System.out.println("You Found it!!!" + permutation);
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
 }
```

its stuck on Antidisestablishmentarian

Can i streamline this?

background on the whole project if you have a better aproach...

my teacher selected a word out of a dictionary, and messed with the case of a few random letters in it... then created the SHA-256 hash value for it, we have been given the hash value and now have to find the word...

i figured i would create a two new dictionary's... use the first one to create all possible options of the upper lowercase combinations, the use that second one to create a third with all the hash values

If i havint supplied enough information please go ahead and ask ill get it up...

UPDATE:  I removed antidisestablishment words from the dictionary file, and now its continuing well past that point... I guess the word was so big i creates so many possible options JVM couldint handle it? i dont know...

UPDATE:  when i run just antidisestablishmentarian

i get this error...

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at hashcodefinder.HashCodeFinder.DictionaryBuilder.getSmallWordList(DictionaryBuilder.java:53)
at hashcodefinder.HashCodeFinder.DictionaryBuilder.createHashDictionary(DictionaryBuilder.java:34)
at hashcodefinder.HashCodeFinder.Launch.main(Launch.java:81)
/home/ryan/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

UPDATE:

I have updated the code to simi working status.... at least it will run through each possible permutation of each word without storing...

I guess my next steps are to devolpe a method to hash the code, the test equality...

i know its not part of the original question but can i just use .equals and test the strings equality?

Additional part to question...

Am i converting the integer hash code `.tostring()` properly? if i use `.equals()` like i am in the code will actually be comparing the hash?

UPDATE:

with this working code i get no positive results.... so i think i am messed up in either converting my instructors hash back into a string

or

comparing my hashes to his....

what do you guys think?

Comment: "antidisestablishmentarian" has 25 characters; there are 33,554,432 ways to capitalise it. Are you sure you want to create a dictionary holding all those possibilities?

Comment: Well I don't know haha, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Check the hash of every possible capitalisation as you calculate it, and then move on to the next without storing it?

Comment: So instead of writing to file, just use .equals , compare , and move on?

Comment: Yes, no point in storing all possibilities.

Comment: Try to understand variation in hash function for all permutation and combinations. Try to find some pattern/model. After that still you left with brute force, use BufferedReader and BufferedWriter to create your new disctionary, to avoid out of memory.

Comment: Can you elaborate or point me to some resources for buffer read/write.? I'm not yet familiar with those capabilities

Comment: If you have additional problems, it's best to ask them as new questions.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the Out-Of-Memory situation: Think about the data sizes involved: for 'antidisestablishmentarian', you create a binarylist[][] with 25 * 2^25 characters - that is about 840M characters, or 1.6GB of memory. In addition, you collapse that binarylist into a wordlist of 2^25 Strings, each with 25 characters - another 1.6 GB.

The key is that you don't have to precompute all the permutations (and their hashes beforehand). The program wouldn't be fast, but for every dictionary word read, you can use a recursive permutation method to create one particular Uppercase/Lowercase permutation, test its hash, and if the hash doesn't match, you continue to the next permutation. This way, only one permutation stays in memory, regardless of how many words the dictionary contains.

Comment: That sounds like the way to go for sure, how might i accomplish this?i have some ideas i guess, maybe switching my loops so the genorate a word, not all the letters permutations in order i guess if that makes sense

Comment: Actually, look at Antonin's C# example. While not an exact match for your problem (the 'len' parameter is not needed, the 'uppers' limit is not needed if you need to find/test all combinations anyway), it should give you the conceptual starting point. The idea is that gen_inner() generates all perms from position 'i' forward by flipping the char at position 'i' back and forth, each time calling itself to generate all perms from position 'i+1' forward as well.

Comment: You are right about the `len`, it brings only 3% of speed (just matter of habit, the piece of code is rather simple to write than top performant). But in case the number of upper characters is expected to be small, the `uppers` parameter can optimize the search and bring huge improvements of average search time. I only do not know if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

No wonder it is slow with all those `System.out.print`, if the algorithm work, get them out. You may run out of memory, it really depends on length of the words. Much better approach would be generate one combination a time, test it/save it and go on. And do not generate garbage if possible. Modify characters in array of characters the length of the word, keep it small -> in cache -> fast.

Is it likely, that there would be only a few changes to the word? Then test all words for few changes first. Do not get stuck in millions of combinations of one long word.

As an inspiration, it is in C#, but that should be very simmilar:

```
protected void gen_inner(char[] s, int len, int i, int uppers)
{
    if (i >= len)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);//do the testing/processing instead
        return;
    }

    if (uppers < len - i)
    {
        gen_inner(s, len, i + 1, uppers);
    }
    if (uppers > 0)
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = char.ToUpper(c);
        gen_inner(s, len, i + 1, uppers - 1);
        s[i] = c;
    }
}

protected void gen(char[] s, int uppers)
{
    gen_inner(s, s.Length, 0, uppers);
}

char[] s = "aaaaa".ToCharArray();
gen(s, 3);
```

gives the output:

```
aaAAA
aAaAA
aAAaA
aAAAa
AaaAA
AaAaA
AaAAa
AAaaA
AAaAa
AAAaa
```